# It is possible to obtain a function $f \in C^{1}([0,1])$, with $a,b \in (0,1)$ such that $f^{\prime}(x) = 1 $ in $[0,a)$ and $f(x) = 0$ in $[b,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

It is possible to obtain a function $f \in C^{1}\left([0,1]\right)$, with $a,b \in (0,1)$ such that $f^{\prime}(x) = 1 $ in $\left[0,a\right)$ and $f(x) = 0$ in $[b,1]$ with $a < b$?

Comment: Can your really call this graph a function? It seems to me there exists an $x\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)$ is not unique?

Comment: I didn't understand? I want to draw a function for example $f \in C^{1}([0,1])$ such that $f^{\prime}(x) = 1$ in $[0,a)$ and $f(x) = 0$ in $[b,1]$.

Comment: they meant that you can draw a vertical line that will cross the graph of your "function" on severall points

Comment: But it was because the drawing is bad, I wanted to draw a function as I said in the previous comment

Comment: You can delete your comments, I edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: Are you assuming that $a<b$ or $a\le b$?

Comment: Yes, sure. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure (I assume $a<b$) with a bit of gluing...
$ f(x) = x + c_1 $ for $ x \in [0,a) $
$ f(x) = c_2 x^2 + c_3 x + c_4 $ for $ x \in [a,b) $ and
$ f(x) = 0 $ for $ x \in [b,1) $

Now solve for $ c_i $. You basically need to find $c_2$ and $c_3$ so that the middle part gives $f'(a)=1$ and $f'(b)=0$, then pick $c_4$ and $c_1$ to get continuity.

As long as $a \ne b $ the determinant for the $2\times2$ system of equations will be non-zero.

Note: At first the middle part was a third degree polynomial but that is not necessary - I have simplified the answer to use a second degree polynomial

Comment: Why $f^{\prime}(b) = 0$?

Comment: why are you sad $f^{\prime}(b) = 0?$

Comment: Did you mean $f(b) = 0$?

Comment: What if I asked that instead of $f(x) = 0$ in $[b,1]$ be $f^{\prime}(x) = 0$ in $[b,1]$ . Would it still be possible?

Comment: You find $c_2$ and $c_3$ such that $ f('b)=0$ otherwise you won't get a $C^1$ function

Comment: Actually $f(x)=0$ implies that $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: you put in your answer $f^{\prime}(b) = 0$. Why?

Comment: True, so it also holds for $f^{\prime}(x) = 0$ in $[b,1]$.

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand why you put $f^{\prime}(b) = 0$ in your answer.